# $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}+\sqrt{\cos(x)}} dx,$ with $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-t$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, substitution

I already solved a few integrals with substitution but in this case I have no idea how to start. How to solve the integral $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}+\sqrt{\cos(x)}} dx,$$where $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-t$ with substitution, can you tell me how to start? 
It would be great!

Comment: don't put math function as question title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x) dx$$
$$\tag1I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}+\sqrt{\cos(x)}} dx,$$
Replace $x$ by $\frac{\pi}2-x$.
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\sin(\frac{\pi}2-x)}}{\sqrt{\sin(\frac{\pi}2-x)}+\sqrt{\cos(\frac{\pi}2-x)}} dx,$$
$$\tag2I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\cos(x)}}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}+\sqrt{\sin(x)}} dx,$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$2I=\int_0^{\pi/2}dx$$
which can be solved easily.

Comment: I always liked solving integrals using techniques that rely on symmetries, whether or not the integral is odd/even etc.. +1.

Comment: awesome solution!!! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

after the substitution we have the integral
$$-\int_{\pi/2}^0{\frac {\sqrt {\cos \left( t \right) }}{\sqrt {\cos \left( t \right) }
+\sqrt {\sin \left( t \right) }}}dt$$